# How do I add a "Select All" option in SQL Server Report Builder without checking "allow multiple values?"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report with a state parameter (integer). The report shows different data based on what state is selected. I would like to add a "Nationwide" option, but I don't want to check "allow multiple values" because there is no need to select multiple states for this report.

Comment: Allow NULLs on the parameter and handle the `NULL` in your query to be a "SELECT all".

Comment: @Larnu Is there a way to allow NOT NULL? I set Nationwide equal to NULL, and that didn't work.

Comment: `@YourParameter = NULL` won't work, as the expression will always evaluate to "unknown". When working with `NULL` you need to use `IS` or `IS NOT`. For example `@YourParameter IS NULL`.

Comment: @Larnu When I put IS NOT NULL in the "Value" box I get the error "Value is not an integer." (My state codes are integers.) I am using the "specify values" section in the "available values" section of the report parameter properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a new value to your patameter query or new item, label "Nation Wide" and  value -1, then in your query if the parameter is equals to -1 don't use a where clause

```
if @parameter = -1
 begin
   select *
   from table
 end 
else 
 begin
   select *
   from table where
   status = @parameter
 end
```

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you much!